# Como usar usar eventos em Js sem html

Tags: javascript, html, eventos, função-anônima

Como faço isso rodar ?

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script language="javascript">
   function teste(){
    alert("oi");
   }
  
    document.getElementById("as").onclick = function(){
     teste();
    }
   
   
   
   
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <input type="button" id="as" value="AQUI">
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mas "isso" que você postou tem html, você quer usar sem html?

Comment: Me expressei mal. Eu gostaria de saber, na verdade, era : como tratar os eventos sem necessariamente fazer uso de atributos html EX: <body onload="//code">. Entendeste ?

Comment: Recomendar de utilizar `setTimeout(function() { // CODE // }, 500);` ... `window.onload` nem roda todos navegadores de versão.

Answer (score 2):

Não está funcionando por que no momento que você pega o elemento, ele ainda não esta pronto para ser carregado pelo JavaScript.
Para isso, é preciso adicionar a seguinte linha:

```
window.onload = function(){
    //seu codigo vai aqui
}
```

Esse script acima será executado quando finalmente a pagina estiver pronta para ser utilizada com JavaScript.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript">
            window.onload = function() {
                function teste() {
                    alert("oi");
                }

                document.getElementById("as").onclick = function() {
                    teste();
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="button" id="as" value="AQUI">
    </body>

</html>
```